# Node.js - convert array-like string to an array

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js project that makes a call to a separate client.  The response from this client is in the format of `["Hello there"]`.  The way I am calling this API from Node.js, the response comes back as a data stream, so my Node.js response is `"[\"Hello There\"]"`.  I just want to return the string itself without the array.  My solution is to convert this data stream to an array, and then fetch the string value from that array, is this possible?  Below is my code so far:

```
const request = http.request(options, function(response) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      //This is not working
      var chunkToArray = chunk.toString('utf-8').replace(/^\[|\]$/g, "").split(", ");
      var arrayToString = chunkToArray[0];
      //res is the response object to the Node API, not the API being called here
      res.setHeader('content-type','application/text');
      res.status(response.statusCode);
      res.send(arrayToString);
      res.end();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Is the string always in this format? Can it be, say `["Hello", "world"]`

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, though I just solved it (of course).  If I use JSON.parse() on the string, it converts it correctly to an object, and I can pull the string from there.

Comment: @user3334871 I would also suggest to do it in `response.on('end')` handler, instead of `response.on('data')` since `data` event is fired for each chunk, you should ideally collect all chunks and then on `end` event, you can  then `JSON.parse()` the entire response

Comment: @siddheshbhasme thanks, that's very useful!